# How to replace a xml file line using sed

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed, xml

I have the following text in File.XML:

```
<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" max-post-size="1073741824" />
```

I would like to replace that with

```
<!-- <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" max-post-size="1073741824" /> -->>
```

I tried

```
sed -i 's/<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" max-post-size="1073741824" /><!-- <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" max-post-size="1073741824" /> -->>' test.xml
```

But got error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert the required chunk (`<!--`) at start (`^`):

```
sed 's/^/<!-- /'
```

**Example:**

```
% var='<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" max-post-size="1073741824" />'

% sed 's/^/<!-- /' <<<"$var"
<!-- <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" max-post-size="1073741824" />
```

---

Just to note, to parse structured data like `xml`, you should use a tool that understands the structure e.g. `xmlstarlet`.

---

**Answer to the edited question:**

You can match precise substring at start and end, in the replacement use `\0` to refer the whole match putting desired replacement substrings around:

```
sed 's/^<http-listener name="default".*>$/<!-- \0 -->>/'
```

**Example:**

```
% var='<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" max-post-size="1073741824" />'

% sed 's/^<http-listener name="default".*>$/<!-- \0 -->>/' <<<"$var"                     
<!-- <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" max-post-size="1073741824" /> -->>
```

Comment: No need for extended regex, you can save `-E`. In the command OP tried there’s an additional ` -->>` at the end of the line, so maybe OP wants `sed 's_<http… />_<!-- & -->>_` – with a different delimiter because the original line contains a slash.

Comment: sed  -i 's_<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" max-post-size="1073741824" />_<!-- & -->_' test.xml @dessert. It works fine. Nice info

Comment: @dessert Nice emoji in there :)

Comment: @dessert `-E` has become sort of a muscle memory...hahaha....